# Regex - only accepts letters, space and -(dash) and no numbers allowed

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

My current Regex is ***/[^0-9]/*** which does not allow numbers only. But the problem is it accepts other characters like () and also it accepts letters with numbers in between. Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make your rules/requirements. If you want to allow only alphabets - hence try

```
@"^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Hint - Apply set theory. If all the characters belong to the universal set. All are allowed. After which you apply a rule : If you dont allow numbers, it means that everything except numbers is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

What about:

```
[a-zA-Z \-]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[-a-zA-Z ]+
```

A dash or letters 'a' to 'z' in either case or a space.

Or, for better international support, consider whether there are named character classes that you can use.  On POSIX systems, you could write:

```
grep -E '^[-[:alpha:] ]+$'
```

for example, and that would pick up accented characters.  There's probably an analogous notation (probably not *that* notation, though) available to you.

Comment: That regex cannot match any digits.  You might need to put anchors at either end `^[-a-zA-Z ]+$` so that the whole string is matched by letters, dashes and blanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can use this regex

```
[^()\d]
```

It does not allow numbers and the brackets () like you wanted. Even the numbers in between won't appear